# Analyse the result of one tennis player from dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I have a pandas dataset of tennis matches, each match has winner player and loser player:

```
match   match_date  winner  loser   score
match1  06June      player1 player2  6-2
match2  08June      player3 player1  6-4
match3  07June      player1 player4  5-6
match4  12June      player4 player3  6-7
```

the dataset is created based on matches, I need to create new dataset, from this one, for each player:

```
player_name  previous_match  result  score
player1      06June           won     6-2
player1      08June           lost    6-4
player1      07June           lost    5-6
```

the issue is that each player can be present in winner column or loser column and the number of players is big.

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `melt`:

```
melted_df  = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['match',"match_date","score"], value_vars=['winner',"loser"], var_name="result", value_name="player_name")
melted_df
```

Output:

```
match   match_date  score   result  player_name
0   match1  06June  6-2 winner  player1
1   match2  08June  6-4 winner  player3
2   match3  07June  5-6 winner  player1
3   match4  12June  6-7 winner  player4
4   match1  06June  6-2 loser   player2
5   match2  08June  6-4 loser   player1
6   match3  07June  5-6 loser   player4
7   match4  12June  6-7 loser   player3
```

And then you can just sort it:

```
melted_df.sort_values(by="player_name")
```

Output:

```
   match  match_date score  result  player_name
0   match1  06June    6-2   winner  player1
2   match3  07June    5-6   winner  player1
5   match2  08June    6-4   loser   player1
4   match1  06June    6-2   loser   player2
1   match2  08June    6-4   winner  player3
7   match4  12June    6-7   loser   player3
3   match4  12June    6-7   winner  player4
6   match3  07June    5-6   loser   player4
```

Comment: thanks, great, I can create a new dataset where each player per one row ?

Comment: `list_dataframes` contains one dataframe per each player. Is this what you want? or you want one single dataframe with all players in it (with one player per row but you can find the same player in different rows)?

Comment: yes, I want one single dataframe with all players in it (with one player per row but you can find the same player in different rows)

Comment: I mean each player row with historical data in one row, for example one row of player1 contains all previous results (so the new dataset will contain each one player per row)... possible ?

Comment: This seems to be different from your original question. So you mean to add multiple columns  with  the match date and the score in the row? I am sorry but it is difficult to understand what you want. Please update the question with the exact desired output. or ask a new question if it's different from the one above (which was `need to create new dataframe for each player`)

Comment: this is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62303704/create-new-dataframe-for-each-tennis-player

Comment: @KhaledKoubaa I think the answer by luigigi is good, did it solve your problem?

Comment: Really sorry but I don't know how to solve that. Good luck! 
btw, reply to luigigi to explain him why you are not satisfied, he may be able to help you!